Get path using FSO.GetAbsolutePathName displaying the result with a forward slash "/"
I have the following code in visual basic script that detects the path and replaces a word with the path
When the code is executed, the word will be replaced by the path. The result will be as follows: C:\projects. What I want is for the result to come out with the slash "/". It should look like this: C:/projects. I have not been able to find the exact function to achieve what I want, I don't know if it exists, or if something should be added or modified in the code.
How could I do to achieve this?
OldTextFile = ".\file.txt" 
NewTextFile = ".\file1.txt" 
ReplaceFrom = "word" 
ReplaceTo = FSO.GetAbsolutePathName(".") 

FSO.CreateTextFile(NewTextFile, 2). _ 
Write(Replace(FSO.OpenTextFile(OldTextFile, 1).ReadAll(), _ 
ReplaceFrom, ReplaceTo, 1, -1, vbTextCompare))


Why do you want a path that looks like C:/projects instead of C:\Projects? In any case, assuming you really need that for some reason, why not just replace C:\ with C:/?

Eh, use the Replace() function, ReplaceTo = Replace(ReplaceTo, "\", "/") done.

@topsail Because in the file I have some with \ that must remain like that.

You can modify your code by adding a Replace function that transforms the backslashes in the ReplaceTo variable.
Here's how you can implement in your code (added to your previous code):
OldTextFile = ".\file.txt"
NewTextFile = ".\file1.txt"
ReplaceFrom = "word"

ReplaceTo = Replace(FSO.GetAbsolutePathName("."), "\", "/")
FSO.CreateTextFile(NewTextFile, 2). _
Write(Replace(FSO.OpenTextFile(OldTextFile, 1).ReadAll(), _
ReplaceFrom, ReplaceTo, 1, -1, vbTextCompare))

Hope that helps!

My mistake was at the beginning with (. Thanks Mahek Sota

This is already covered in an answer from over 13 years ago, there is nothing new here. There are also numerous other examples of Replace() and how to use it in various questions already on [so].
